# Selection Sort in SML with a Twist

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I'm starting to become more familiar with sml, but this problem has thrown me for a loop.  What I need to do is perform selection sort on a list, but the twist is that all of the even numbers need to proceed the odd.

For example:

```
selSort[1, 6, 9, 3, 8, 4, 7, 2, 5, 3];
val it = [2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9] : int list
```

I can't get my head around doing this without having some sort of for-loop or variables to assist me.  As I'm new to sml, any input would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data structures in functional languages are generally *immutable*; that is, they cannot be modified once created. So you can't perform in-place swaps like you would in an iterative array-based implementation. Instead, you need to write a function which takes your original list as an argument, and returns an independent copy of it with your desired changes.

For example, look at the built-in function `rev`. It returns the reversed version of whatever list you pass it, but it does not (indeed, it *can* not) alter the structure of the original list.

In this case, you probably want a function `min(xs)` to find the smallest element `x` in `xs`, and a function `remove(x,xs)` which returns a copy of `xs` with `x` removed (let's call it `remainder`). Then just recursively sort `remainder`, and prepend `x` to the result.

Instead of using `<` to compare elements in `min`, you can enforce this unusual ordering by defining your own comparison function `lessThan`, where `lessThan(x,y)` is always true if `x` is even and `y` is odd.

```
fun lessThan(x,y) = (x mod 2 = 0 and y mod 2 = 1) or (x mod 2 = y mod 2 and x < y)
```

Now just replace any instance of `x < y` in your `min(xs)` function with `lessThan(x,y)`.

Better yet, write a version `selSort(list,comp)` which takes a comparison function `comp` as an argument. Then you can pass it `(op <)` to perform a standard sort, `lessThan` to perform this "sort with a twist", or even use it sort non-integer lists (as long as you give it a comparison function with a corresponding type).

Comment: Thank you for your response, this will definitely be helpful. My biggest problem is figuring out how to get the selection sort working.  In java I would program it to where it will iterate through an array, make a swap, update my indexes and recurse.  In sml I don't have the luxury of indexes and swapping (to my knowledge).  So, I don't know how I would go about setting this up.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was just the "twist" that was throwing you off. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Genius.  This has helped a ton.  Thank you.